# Insertion in text editorsI

Tags: string, text

I'm wondering on a question about I/O that as I can see it's handled everywhere but I fail to see how its done.

Let's say we have a file with text, and we're making a text editor program (or something similar) the program should be able to open that file and treat it as a string of characters. Adding characters to the end of the string should be fairly easy but I'm not really sure on how to implement insertion at the middle of the string. How is this usually handled? Is there a better method than copying the whole string? Everything that comes up looks really inefficient to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **is** ineffective, but it's usually done like that.

One method to make this a bit more effective is storing the text in an array of strings with each line being represented by its own string. Now you would only have to modify a (probably much) shorter string if you edit a line, or relink the items if you insert one.